# How to return matched nested objects with elastic-search

Tags: elasticsearch

Given the documents below, how would I search and return only the matched nested object. I would like the query to return the journal information with only the second nested article since that's the one being matched in the query.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "isn" : { "type":"text" },
      "title" : { "type":"text" },
      "article": {
        "type": "nested" 
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT journal/_doc/1
{
  "isn" : "11223344",
  "article" : [
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "title" : "first article title",
      "author" :  "John"
    },
    {
      "id" : 2,
      "title" : "second article title",
      "author" :  "Carl"
    }
  ]
}

GET journal/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "article",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "article.title": "second" }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is ask for `inner_hits` like below in your query :

```
GET journal/_search
{
  "_source": false, 
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "article",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "article.title": "second" }}
          ]
        }
      }
      , "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the response has a specific scheme :

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.6931472,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "journal",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.6931472,
        "inner_hits" : {
          "article" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 0.6931472,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "journal",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "article",
                    "offset" : 1
                  },
                  "_score" : 0.6931472,
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "title" : "second article title",
                    "author" : "Carl"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```